# How to find records and append them in another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files, file A and file B.

Contents of file A are like this:

```
1 a 
2 b 
3 c
```

Contents of file B are like this:

```
3 cc 
1 aa  
2 bb
```

How can I append the second column from file B to file A by matching the first column as keys?

Expected output are like this:

```
1 a aa 
2 b bb 
3 c cc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a rather easy job, and `awk` is really the tool you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,a[$1]}' fileb filea
```

or

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,$2,a[$1]}' fileb filea
```

But please, show your own efforts next time, how you searched/tried and failed.
Help yourself, help others to help you.